# Find all functions $f \colon \Bbb R \rightarrow \Bbb R $ that satisfy.....

Tags: inequality, functional-inequalities

I find the following problem interesting :

> Find all functions $f \colon \Bbb R \rightarrow \Bbb R $ that satisfy the inequality
>   $f(x+y)+f(y+z)+f(z+x) \geq 3f(x+2y+3z)?$

How Can I tackle the problem? Any hints will be appreciated.

Comment: a source of the problem it is from 26th russian mathematical olympiad at 2000. Problem 9. http://equation-solver.blogspot.gr/2010/11/26th-all-russian-mathematical-olympiad.html

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos with regards to your edit of my edit, I disagree that [tag:functional-inequalities] should be independent of [tag:functional-equations].

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Plugging in $x=t,y=0,z=0$ yields $$f(0) \geq f(t), \tag{1}$$ and plugging in $x=t/2,y=t/2,z=-t/2$ yields $$f(t) \geq f(0). \tag{2}$$

Hence, from $(1)$ and $(2),$ we get $f(t)=f(0) \quad \forall t$,so $f$ must be constant.
Conversely, any constant function $f$ clearly satisfies the given condition.

Comment: (+1) I formatted it to look a little nicer. Check it out to see how I did it.

Comment: @CameronBuie thanks a lot for making it look nice.